# How to solve [MJSONWP] Encountered internal Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries error when automating with Appium and iOS?

Tags: java, ios, selenium-webdriver, ios-simulator, appium-ios

I am trying to automate a hybrid app with Appium 1.7.1 and Java, iOS simulator.Xcode 8.3

So far I was able to launch the app and remove the notifications pop up but when trying to get the contexts an error is thrown in Appium:

> [MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries.
>       at Object.wrappedLogger.errorAndThrow (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-support/lib/logging.js:63:13)
>       at RemoteDebugger.selectApp$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-remote-debugger/lib/remote-debugger.js:259:6)
>       at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as throw] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
>   [HTTP] <-- GET /wd/hub/session/c59dd263-05e2-439a-9f1e-c37389e38ada/contexts 500 136 ms - 219

And on the IDE:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not connect to a valid app after 20 tries. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

Code:

```
package XYZ;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.MobileElement;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import jdk.internal.instrumentation.Logger;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * Created by on 28/11/2017.
 */
public class AppSimulatorLaunch {




    public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPad Air 2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "10.3");
        capabilities.setCapability("nativeWebTap", true);
        capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        capabilities.setCapability("xcodeOrgId", "xyz");
        capabilities.setCapability("xcodeSigningId", "iPhone Developer");
        capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", "120");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/user/Documents/xyz.app");

        driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();


    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {

      // driver.quit();
    }


    @Test
    public void testCheckWebsite() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();
        System.out.println("about to print the context list");
        System.out.println(contextNames);

         driver.context((String) contextNames.toArray()[1]);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"USER\"]")).sendKeys("t334658");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"PASSWORD\"]")).sendKeys("geenidee01");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"bouton1\"]")).click();

    }

}
```

Any idea how to solve this? I've tried adding a thread.sleep as mentioned in https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6825 but it does not seem to work either.

AutoTig

Comment: you mean your test is failing at `Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles();` ?

Comment: Yes exactly, it fails on  Set<String> contextNames = driver.getContextHandles()

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigations the problem apparently was running the script with Xcode 8.3 and Appium 1.7.1.
With Xcode 9 it seems to work.